# AdehabitatHR kerneloverlaphr

Tags: r

Hope someone can help. I have a large data set which includes 100 runs of random data for 10 animals. So far I have created an EstUD by stacking each of the runs to get a sum of utilised distribution. I would now like to compare each animals home range using kerneloverlaphr. Unfortunatley I get the error, In vi * vj : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length. I think it is because the grids are not all the same. Is there a way to convert the grids so they are all the same then I can estimate overlap please? The first part of the code I have run ten times, once for each animal. I'm sure this could be done in a loop too but not sure how.

```
#Part1: generate 10 estUD's 1 per animal
bat.master <- read.csv("C:/Users/a6915409/Dropbox/Wallington GIS/bat.master")

xybat <- subset(bat.master, bat.master$id == "H1608b",select=x:loopno )

#change to spatial points
xy <- xybat[1:2]#first two rows save as coords
df <- xybat[-1:-3]#remove unneded columns for ud

SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy, data=df)#combine df and xy

udHR <- kernelUD(SPDF, h = "href", same4all = TRUE, kern = "bivnorm") 


## I would proceed using the raster packages
library(raster)
ud <- stack(lapply(udHR, raster))

## take the sum
plot(udm <- sum(ud))

H1608b <- udHR[[1]]
H1608b@grid <- as(udm, "GridTopology")

# Part 2: 
#combine all Ud's into one dataset

liud <- list(Y2889a, Y2889a, Y2850a, Y2850b, H1670a, H1670b, H1659a, H1659b,H1608a, H1608b)
class(liud) <- "estUDm"

image(liud)#plot all est ud's

Over<-kerneloverlaphr(liud, method="UDOI", percent= 90)
```

error: In vi * vj : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: `kerneloverlaphr` expects a object of class `estUDm`, but you are providing it a `list`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The line class(liud)<-"estUDm" converts the list to an object of estUDm does it not? I have now managed to do a kerneloverlaphr by changing the value of h and grid size but getting an error on getvertices. *Sigh

Comment: No it does not, I just overwrites the class name but does not convert it. Update your question with the progress you made, and I will have an other look at it.

Comment: Hi, I have asked as a new question yesterday please see..why is subscript out of bounds in adehabitatHR getvertices (puechabonsp data)
http://stackoverflow.com/q/27376315/3237130?sem=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to estimate the kernelUD using the argument same4all=T. You will eliminate the problems regarding overlapping calculations.